# I want to re order the divs in Bootstrap on mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color:#36F;height:150px;">First Section</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12" style="background-color:#F30;height:150px;">Second Section</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color:#F90;height:150px;">Third Column</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-xs-pu11-12"style="background-color:#CF0;height:150px;">Fourth Column</div>
```

On mobile view I want the Fourth column should appear on top and Column first should appear at last

Comment: Please provide more details with code snap

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the latest version of Bootstrap, you can use the "push" and "pull" modifier classes, like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**Resources:**

- http://www.getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering